# How to change the gravity of a clipdrawable

Tags: android, drawable

I have defined a clipdrawable component in XML file, I set the gravity attribute to be left, How can I change this value at runtime to be **right**.

The following represents the "clip.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:drawable="@drawable/image" 
android:clipOrientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="left" />
```

Here where I'm using this clipdrawable in "activity_main.xml"

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/effect_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/clip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutmain"
    android:layout_above="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
/>
```

Comment: show your xml please

Comment: the above is the required xml.

Comment: You can't change the gravity of a `ClipDrawable` - you will have to create a new instance of it.